# How to load a linux module at specific time during boot on a machine running systemd

Tags: linux, systemd

I tried  using a configuration file in /etc/modules-load.d/ and it worked too.
My driver is able to be loaded at boot time.

What I am looking for is how to be able to load my driver at specific time during boot, much before the "UI" has been loaded, for example - I want my driver to be loaded as soon as **the the file system on  which the kernel booted is loaded.**

Or I might want to be able to load my driver before any Network Work is started, before any packet goes out the HBA attached.

That is the pattern I am looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Modules listed in configuration files in the `/etc/modules-load.d` directory are loaded by [systemd-modules-load.service](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-modules-load.service.html). This service is started [before `sysinit.target`](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/blob/master/units/systemd-modules-load.service.in), which thus guarantee (see order in [bootup(7)](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/bootup.html)) that it will load all modules before starting any UI related programs, network configuration daemon or scripts.

If you want to load another module at another specific time you should create a separate service unit and order it depending on when you want it to be started.